# Firestore Reference Key (AutoID) is behaving wierd inside FOR loop

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/StoryMode/de73b04v/20/) which replicates the problem. I'm using a test database for this, so don't worry about the data being used improperly.

My Data is this:

```
slides{
  42rJA379fssKUe11KuCB{
    slideTitle: "Sample Title 4"
  }
  Sp4611QJwQ9GrE2nLauZ{
    slideTitle: "Sample Title 3"
  }
  VfwrwjNFitutSUUzmViE{
    slideTitle: "Sample Title 1"
  }
  W6y1aQKJRxTRV2Jnwd2q{
    slideTitle: "Sample Title 2"
  }
}
```

The Code I'm using is this:

```
slideArray = ["42rJA379fssKUe11KuCB", "Sp4611QJwQ9GrE2nLauZ", "VfwrwjNFitutSUUzmViE", "W6y1aQKJRxTRV2Jnwd2q"];

for(var i = 0; i < slideArray.length; i++){
  slideKey = slideArray[i];
  console.log('Outside the slide key is:' + slideKey);
  db.collection('slides').doc(slideKey).get().then(function(snap){
    console.log('Inside the slide key is' + slideKey);
    console.log('The slides Title prints correctly however: ' + snap.data().slideTitle);
  })
}
```

The output I get is this:

```
Outside the slide key is: Sp4611QJwQ9GrE2nLauZ
Outside the slide key is: VfwrwjNFitutSUUzmViE
Outside the slide key is: W6y1aQKJRxTRV2Jnwd2q
Inside the slide key is W6y1aQKJRxTRV2Jnwd2q
The slides Title prints correctly however: Sample Title 4
Inside the slide key is W6y1aQKJRxTRV2Jnwd2q
The slides Title prints correctly however: Sample Title 3
Inside the slide key is W6y1aQKJRxTRV2Jnwd2q
The slides Title prints correctly however: Sample Title 1
Inside the slide key is W6y1aQKJRxTRV2Jnwd2q
The slides Title prints correctly however: Sample Title 2
```

What I expect it to do:

So as you can see that it is printing the correct Sample Titles. That means that it gets the data of every loop. However the slideKey inside is always the last Key in the array. I expect the slideKey inside the function to be the current one. How can I achieve that?

Also outside the loop, the first key is not displayed? Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every iteration of the loop generates a promise (via `.get()`) which is resolved and consumed (`.then(...)`) in a later iteration of the JavaScript event loop.
By that time your callbacks are invoked, `slideKey` will always be equal to the last element in the loop.

You can easily fix it by using `slideArray.forEach(function(slideKey) {...})`. Every invocation of the loop will happen in a new function scope, so each invocation sees a different `slideKey` variable.

If your target environment is new enough, you can also use ES5 arrow functions like so: `slideArray.forEach(slideKey => { ... })`.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the explanation and the solution. That worked for me :D